# Change presentation of list-columns in RStudio

Tags: r, tibble

I would like to change how dataframe/tibble list columns, containing atomic vectors, print and also display when inspected with View() in RStudio.

```
l <- list("numbers" = 1:10,
          "letters" = LETTERS[1:10])

# to dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(base::t(l))
print(df)

# to tibble
tb <- tibble::as_tibble(base::t(l))
print(tb)
```

Which such data, dataframes print like this:

[image]

And tibbles like this:

[image]

An ideal printing display would be a combination, where you can see the contents of the vector, as in the dataframe view, but with the type displayed, like in a tibble (so you know it's a vector of length > 1 and not e.g., a character string).

Also, when you View() the dataframe in RStudio, it looks like this:

[image]

This is a big ugly, since it prints the c() marks. I would rather that it prints out like a normal string of length 1..

[image]

... but perhaps in a different colour to signify that it's not really a string under the hood, but indeed a vector of length > 1.

Are these things possible with current standard features and/or packages?

Comment: Are you talking about printing just in the console & view panel, or for output somewhere like a PDF? If the console, you could mess around with the `pillar` package that `tibble` uses, but since the console isn't really meant for presentation it might become more trouble than it's worth

Comment: This is resident in [`pillar`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pillar/index.html), responsible for *"formatting columns of data"*. There's already a github issue [r-lib/pillar#403](https://github.com/r-lib/pillar/issues/403) (stemming from [tidyverse/tibble#892](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/892)) that is looking into showing the contents of list-columns. (The pillar issue is currently tagged with the [r-lib/pillar%1.7.0](https://github.com/r-lib/pillar/milestone/10) milestone, though that may change.)

Comment: The problem is that what you are asking for is actually pretty ambiguous and case specific. If you print out all the elements in the list, you will end up with massively wide tibble columns rendering the whole view unreadable (except with short lists). And then in the `View()` box, if you remove the "c(" component, how do you know its a vector and not just a single string with commas in it? I am not saying you are wrong to want that, I am saying that the feature is unlikely to be there because it wouldn't work in a generalized setting.

Comment: @Adam, it doesn't *need* to be all elements in the list that get printed; just as many as takes up the cell/standard area, for instance. I already suggested that the font colour could be changed to signify the different type.

Comment: @eartoolbox I hear you. I see the appeal in certain settings for sure. I just think its a bit specialized and am doubtful there is a switch somewhere that you can flip to easily get that view.

Comment: I'm not expecting a switch, I realised I would need to combine some things. pillar sounds useful, thank @r2evans. For me this would be very useful because the list columns hold data in a way that is useful for my ongoing purposes, yet viewing is not helpful, and I constantly need to check data at the cell level.

Comment: FYI, `data.table::as.data.table(df)` looks more like what you are envisioning, and I think it is close to what the changes to pillar might display.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans that is interesting.